# LINQ query grouping by column in child table and ordering the results within the groups

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, sql-order-by, inner-join

I have two tables: Resources and ResourceCategories. For the sake of this question they can simply have the following structures:

Resource

```
public long Id { get; set; }
public string DisplayText { get; set; }
public long CategoryId { get; set; }

public virtual ResourceCategory ResourceCategory { get; set; }
```

ResourceCategory

```
public long Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
```

I want to return a list of resources grouped by resource category `Name` and ordered by resource `DisplayText` within each group. I can easily get the grouping working but I cannot work out the ordering.

I basically want:

```
Resource Category 1
    Resource A
    Resource D
    Resource K
Resource Category 2
    Resource C
    Resource F
    Resource M
...
```

The code for the grouping is very simple:

```
model.CategorisedResources = _db.Resources
    .GroupBy(r => r.ResourceCategory.Name);
```

How can I achieve the ordering of each group by the resource `DisplayText`?

Note that the `CategorisedResources` property of the model is currently of type:

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, Resource>>
```

but that possibly could be changed, if necessary.

Comment: LINQ to SQL or LINQ to Entities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by first Sort your list and then Group them

```
_db.Resources
.OrderBy(r=>r.DisplayText).ToList()
.GroupBy(r => r.ResourceCategory.Name);
```

Comment: I have tried this and the `OrderBy` seems to have no effect.

Comment: For the record, this is not LINQ to Entities solution at all.

Comment: Because `ToList()` is materialing the query result in memory, so the rest is just LINQ to Objects.

Answer (score 0):

In order to specify the sort order within a group, you can specify the `resultSelector` argument to the `GroupBy` method:

```
model.CategorisedResources = _db.Resources.GroupBy(r => 
    r.ResourceCategory.Name, (catName, catRes) => catRes.OrderBy(cr => cr.DisplayText));
```

Comment: This results in an `IQueryable<IOrderedEnumerable<Resource>>`, and I seem to have lost my `ResourceCategory.Name` grouping.

Comment: It's not lost. Category name is part of the resource itself. Just navigate to: `.ResourceCategory.Name`

Comment: What I mean is, I have lost the grouping. I can longer loop through the groups (categories) and then, within that, loop through the resources.